# Set the tmux socket via configuration

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux

I regularly SSH to a Linux server that is set up with a proxy that randomly redirects you to one of two actual servers that share a filesystem. This means that, if I `tmux attach`, I'll be assigned to one of two actual `tmux` sessions that live in the `/tmp` of the respective machines. I would rather have one session using one socket that I can access from either machine.

The obvious solution to this is to use `tmux -S /path/on/shared/filesystem` each time, but this is annoying to type each time, and I'm likely to forget the path to this socket.

Is there a way to set the default socket in the config file, using an environment variable etc so that two different machines can "share" a socket, in a way that's automatic, once it's configured?

Comment: There's the `TMUX_TMPDIR` env var, but I'm not entirely sure if it suits you setup / need. Try it and see maybe.

Comment: not quite sure what you want but the [unix domain socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) cannot really be shared between machines. just fyi.